# Subdivision Surface not making things smooth as they are in the tutorial I am following

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I am currently trying to develop my modeling skills, and following a tutorial found on YouTube. The tutorial teaches how to create an anvil. At 19:10 or so into the video, a subdivision surface modifier is used to create a smooth, soft look.

However, when I do the same, mine looks very sharp and generally bad.

Any ideas why? I will include the blend file below, I appreciate your time and suggestions.

[The Tutorial I'm following (skip to about 19:00)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxMwa0njGSM)

This is his when he subdivides, which is very different from mine when I do the same at the same settings. (I cannot post more pictures because I am new, but if you check the blend file I attached, you should be able to see the difference.
[image: My issue]

This is what it looks like when I subsurf without the base face.

[image]

Comment: This is the blend file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3676" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3676/)

Comment: Looks like it's somewhat unclear in the tutorial about the converting bottom Ngon into the quads. You have Ngon (face with > 4 vertices) in the bottom and several double vertices in the mesh, this will break subsurfing.

Comment: I tried removing the doubles by selecting everything and clicking the remove doubles button, however it says that there are no verticies removed. By the ngon, are you referring to the base? If so, what would be an appropriate way to reduce it to a quad (perhaps the knife?) Also, I will add pictures to demonstrate later, when i get back home

Comment: @jonesnoh Could you post your original image so the in the future people with similar problems will fully understand your original question? Thanks :)

Comment: I will when I'm back home!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delete the bottom face. Select it and press "X" and select "Faces" from the dropdown menu.

[image]

After you delete the bottom face an additional problem for your Modifiers/mesh occurs.

Set the "view" and "render" to 2 in the Sub Surf Modifier.

[image]

In Edit Mode select all of the vertices and press "G" "Y" to move them slightly away from the center on the Y axis.

[image]

Then check the box next to "Clipping" in the Mirror Modifier. Then "G" "Y" again and move all of your vertices back toward the center.

[image]

Comment: Okay,  I tried that, and it definitely looks a lot better, however, there still are some issues, is there any way to post more pictures? It says I cannot post more than two links because I am below rank 10

Comment: See additional info I just added

Comment: Hmmm, I also tried that, but that didn't seem to change much :/ I'm going to replace the above image with the issue I'm having so you can get a better idea of my problem :)

Comment: @ jonesnoh please do not do that. Create a NEW question... thanks.

Comment: even though it's the same issue? I'm totally fine with creating a new question I just though it would be easier for you to find if it was on the same page

Comment: I'm adding some images that may help.

Comment: That definitely helps, I wasn't pushing them close enough together for the overlay to cover that middle gap, thank you Do you happen to know about that deformity on the right side in the picture I posted?

Comment: There isn't any deformity like that in the .blend you uploaded. So, maybe download it and use that. Other wise that would be a separate question. The Stack Exchange like to only one question at a time. You are welcome to post as many separate questions as you like. If you think your initial question has been solved please mark it as solved. Happy Blendering.

Answer (score 0):

**Catmul Clark**

Please try to experiments with the following high lighted options

[image]

Also you may use the smooth
[image]

**Simple** 
[image]

Comment: Hmmm, my main issue is that when my settings are the same as the tutorial's mine still looks morphed. I'll upload pictures later when i get home to compare.

Comment: Please let me know when you ready with picture

Comment: I uploaded a picture, unfortunately I cannot upload more because I am new, however, if you check out the blend file I attached, when subsurfed, it contrasts the picture I included above, let me know if you need more information or clarification :)

Comment: @Mr Zak,  are you referring to the base, as if looking at the model from numpad 9? If so, I understand what you're saying. How would I go about fixing that? Would a knife be the way to go? Also, I tried removing the doubles but it says no vertices were removed... :/