# After a boolean operation and clean up, I still have an issue with subsurface

Tags: modifiers

I'm following Andrew Price tutorial to create an anvil and I'm really new at blender.
I cleaned up all my faces making sure they all had 4 vertices only and when I select with <kbd>ALT</kbd> and face, they seem to flow well.

[image: Mesh Screenshot]

But when I apply the subsurface I still get ONE vertex left in the middle of my old cylinder which I had erased and therefore the cut out is weird.

[image: Mesh Screenshot With Subdivision Surface Modifier]

Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87943/subdivision-surface-not-making-things-smooth-as-they-are-in-the-tutorial-i-am-fo

Comment: try deleting that single middle face at the bottom of the image (the black dot floating at the bottom of the anvil.)

Comment: Yeah, I see one face dot there that should not be there. You need to clean up the geometry on the bottom of the anvil.