# Why is the subdivision surface modifier still being distorted?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

well I had a problem with vertices and 5 edges, which I know is the cause of the subdivision modifier distortion problem, I fixed that, but as you see in the image there are no 5 edges, and I removed the double vertices in the options, but still the textures get distorted... Any suggestions , or am I just missing something ? Thx :)[image: blender vertices image]

Comment: The infamous anvil... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87943/subdivision-surface-not-making-things-smooth-as-they-are-in-the-tutorial-i-am-fo and https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=anvil